# Apache Expires Directive on Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, undertow

Is there any way to replicate Apache Expires Directive functionality on Wildfly using undertow-handlers or standalone.xml . Below are the directives -

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 120 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 120 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 120 minutes"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 60 minutes"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 60 minutes"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 60 minutes"
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 60 minutes"
</IfModule>
```

Going through Wildfly documentation didn't help much.

Comment: Do you mean for the entire server or a single webapp?  A very simple filter could do this but I don't think that there is anything built in.

Comment: @stdunbar at which level do we need to implement the filter? and how do we do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to set a header for a type but you can use suffices instead.
You can configure a `response-header` filter for specific suffixes. In your example you would need one `filter-ref` and one `response-header` for all suffixes of a type.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">

  ...

  <server name="default-server">

    ...

    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        ...
        <filter-ref name="custom-max-age" predicate="path-suffix['.js'] or path-suffix ['.json'] or path-suffix ['.html'] or path-suffix ['.css'] or path-suffix ['.jpg'] or path-suffix ['.jpeg'] or path-suffix ['.png'] or path-suffix ['.gif']"/>
    </host>
  </server>

  ...

  <filters>

      ...
      
      <response-header name="custom-max-age" header-name="Cache-Control" header-value="max-age=600, public"/>
  </filters>
</subsystem>
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/remibantos/5e86829e1ba6ad64eea1)